# Expo - React Native - iOS - How to drag and drop between 2 apps in split view / split over

Tags: ios, react-native, drag-and-drop, expo, splitview

I would like to drag elements (like images) from one app (Safari for example) to my app made with Expo.
Despite searching GitHub, Stackoverflow, etc. i can't find how do that ?
Is it then possible to use the Expo workflow version only ?

Comment: Did you solve this or found a library?

Comment: Unfortunatly, i'm still stuck with that feature ...

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution.
You can use **webview** and then use **ondrop** function.

check this video ::
https://youtu.be/eLja90T28AQ